# Calculating $\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{a+b\sin^2(x)} dx $

Tags: integration

How do I calculate this integral? $a \gt b$ is given.

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{a+b\sin^2(x)} dx $$

I am confused since [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F%28a%2Bb*sin%5E2%28x%29%29+dx) says one the one hand, that $F(\pi) = F(0) = 0 $ , but with some [random values](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F%282%2Bsin%5E2%28x%29%29+dx+from+x%3D0+to+x%3Dpi)  it isn't 0.

What am I missing?

Note that I am not really interested in a complete antiderivative, I am more interested in a $G(a,b) = F(\pi) - F(0) = \, ... $

Comment: Try sunstituting $sinx = \frac{2tanx}{1+tan^{2} x}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The antiderivative
$$
F(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+b}} \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{a+b} \tan x}{\sqrt{a}}\right)
$$
given by WA isn't continuous on the whole interval $[0,\pi]$
(because it contains $\tan x$ which jumps at $x=\pi/2$),
and this is why $F(\pi)-F(0)$ doesn't give the right answer.
(Clearly, the answer "zero" is wrong, since the integrand is *positive*!)

On the other hand, $F(x)$ *is* continuous on the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, and extends continuously to the endpoints by taking limits, and your integrand has period $\pi$ so we can integrate over *any* interval of length $\pi$ without changing the integral's value. So
$$
\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{a+b\sin^2(x)} dx
= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{a+b\sin^2(x)} dx
= \lim_{x\to(\pi/2)^-} F(x) - \lim_{x\to(-\pi/2)^+} F(x)
= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+b}}
$$
works.

You can find some articles about "gotchas" of this kind in computer algebra systems if you search the web for "D. J. Jeffrey continuous".

Comment: Are you sure it's $\sqrt{\pi}$ and not $\pi$ ? It's actually a physics problem and the solution is given ("Prove that..."). With your integral I get the wished result, but it's $\pi$ and not $\sqrt{\pi}$ ...

Comment: Also I think $\arctan(+\infty) = \pi/2 $ and $\arctan(-\infty) = -\pi/2 $, so the difference is $ \pi $ ?

Comment: @Christian: Yes, of course it should be $\pi$. That was a contamination from all the other square roots... Anyway, I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\sin^2 x} dx.$$

Put  $z   =  \exp(ix)$  so  that   $dz  =  i\exp(ix) \;  dx$  and  hence
$\frac{dz}{iz} = dx$ to obtain
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{|z|=1}
\frac{1}{a+b(z-1/z)^2/4/(-1)}\frac{dz}{iz}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \int_{|z|=1}
\frac{4}{4a-b(z-1/z)^2}\frac{dz}{iz}
\\ = \frac{2}{i} \int_{|z|=1}
\frac{z}{4a-b(z-1/z)^2}\frac{dz}{z^2}
\\ = \frac{2}{i} \int_{|z|=1}
\frac{z}{4az^2-b(z^2-1)^2} dz
\\ = \frac{2}{i} \int_{|z|=1}
\frac{z}{-bz^4+(2b+4a)z^2-b} dz.$$

The poles here are all simple and located at
$$\rho_{1,2,3,4}
= \pm\sqrt{\frac{2a+b}{b} \pm 
\frac{2\sqrt{a^2+ab}}{b}}.$$

Re-write this as
$$\rho_{1,2,3,4}
= \pm\sqrt{1+\frac{2a}{b} \pm 
\frac{2\sqrt{a^2+ab}}{b}}.$$

With $a$ and  $b$ positive the first two poles  are clearly not inside
the contour (modulus larger than one). That leaves
$$\rho_{3,4}
= \pm\sqrt{1+\frac{2a}{b}
- \frac{2\sqrt{a^2+ab}}{b}}.$$

Now we have
$$1+\frac{2a}{b} 
- \frac{2\sqrt{a^2+ab}}{b} < 1$$
and also
$$1+\frac{2a}{b} 
- \frac{2\sqrt{a^2+ab}}{b} > 0$$
since
$$(b+2a)^2 = b^2+4ab+4a^2 > 4(a^2+ab)$$
and therefore these poles are indeed inside the contour.

The residues are given by
$$\left. \frac{z}{-4bz^3+2(2b+4a)z}
\right|_{z=\rho_{3,4}}
= \left. \frac{1}{-4bz^2+2(2b+4a)}
\right|_{z=\rho_{3,4}}.$$

This is
$$\frac{1}{-4b-8a+8\sqrt{a^2+ab}
+2(2b+4a)}
= \frac{1}{8\sqrt{a^2+ab}}.$$

It follows that the desired value is
$$\frac{2}{i}\times 2\pi i
\times \frac{2}{8\sqrt{a^2+ab}}
= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+b}}.$$