# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Confusion regarding atan

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

According to [this site](http://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-2/integral-calculator/?f=1%2F%28a%5E2+cos%5E2%28x%29%2Bb%5E2+sin%5E2%28x%29%29&var=&steps=on),

$$ \int \frac{1}{a^2 \cos^2(x) + b^2 \sin^2(x)} \,dx =\frac{1}{ab} \arctan\left(\frac{b}{a} \tan(x)\right)$$

Thus,
$$ \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{a^2 \cos^2(x) + b^2 \sin^2(x)} \, dx =\frac{1}{ab} \arctan\left(\frac{b}{a} \tan(\pi)\right)-\frac{1}{ab} \arctan\left(\frac{b}{a} \tan(0)\right)=0-0=0$$

But in fact value of integral is not zero.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My first thought is that the arctangent function is somewhat problematic.  It is an inverse only of a restriction of the tangent function. $\qquad$

Comment: I believe it is because $\arctan(0)$ is not always $0$, e.g. it could also be $\pi$. In that sense $\arctan$ is a multi-valued function.

Comment: Let $a=b=1$. Then $\frac{1}{ab} \arctan\left(\frac{b}{a} \tan(\pi)\right)
=\frac{1}{ab} \arctan 0 = 0 \ne \pi$. Your equation only works on $(-\pi, \pi)$

Comment: See [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1ms6oibnug). Your function is not continuous, that's why it works only on $(-\pi/2;\pi/2)$

Comment: Some related questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296351/calculating-int-0-pi-frac1ab-sin2x-dx, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356523/what-are-the-restrictions-on-using-substitution-in-integration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, let us assume that $a, b > 0$ without loss of generality.  Then in this regime, $f(x) = (a^2 \cos^2 x + b^2 \sin^2 x)^{-1}$ is clearly a well-defined function everywhere, and is periodic with period $\pi$.  However, the antiderivative is not unique, and the particular choice of antiderivative $$F(x) = \frac{1}{ab} \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{b}{a} \tan x \right)$$ may not be continuous over a given interval.  For example, if we choose the branch of $\tan^{-1}$ that restricts the range to lie in $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, then you get this picture for $a = 2$, $b = 0.5$:

[image]

As you can see, there is a jump discontinuity in the antiderivative at $x = \pi/2$ that could be rectified by choosing a different branch of the inverse tangent; e.g., we could choose $\tan^{-1}$ to have the range $[0,\pi)$.  This fixes the discontinuity at $\pi/2$ so that a definite integral containing this point will not result in an incorrect evaluation.

[image]

In general, it is important when dealing with branches of multivalued functions to choose the branch appropriate to the interval or domain of integration, so as to avoid these problems.

---

An example of how you could specify an antiderivative that is continuous for all real $x$ **provided** that we state that the range of $\tan^{-1}$ is $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, is by writing it as $$F(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac{1}{ab} \left( \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{b}{a} \tan x \right) + \pi \left(\lfloor 2x/\pi \rfloor - \lfloor x/\pi \rfloor\right) \right), & 2x/\pi \not \in \{\pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots\} \\ \displaystyle \frac{x}{ab}, & 2x/\pi \in \{\pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots\}. \end{cases}$$ 
But I think this is a rather complicated way to express the antiderivative.  Instead, it might be better to state that the branch of the inverse tangent that is chosen depends on the argument of $x$; i.e., if we define $y = \tan^{-1} c \tan x$ for some $0 < c < \infty$, then $y$ is chosen such that $x, y \in ((2m-1)\pi/2, (2m+1)\pi/2)$ for a suitable integer $m$.

Comment: What is the value of antiderivative then? Where should a shift occur?

Comment: So, what is antiderivative in this particular case? If we take integer m then 2m-1 is never 0. How we then choose interval (0,pi)?

Comment: You've completely misunderstood the issue. When I wrote an alternative form of $F(x)$, that form uses a definition of inverse tangent such that $\tan^{-1} x \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.  Plot it yourself and you will see it is continuous.  If you choose to define $\tan^{-1} x$ in a way that its range is on $[0,\pi)$, then that formula doesn't work.  The formula doesn't determine the choice of branch:  it is **your** choice of branch that determines what a formula looks like.

Comment: That's the question. What is the formula for inverse tangent, whose range is [0, pi)?

Answer (score 4):

Note that, in the link, $u=\tan x$ which is increasing in $[0,\pi/2)$. In this integral, $x\in[0,\pi]$ and hence you can't use the result directly. In fact

$$ \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{a^2 \cos^2(x) + b^2 \sin^2(x)} \,dx=2\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{a^2 \cos^2(x) + b^2 \sin^2(x)} \,dx.$$
Use the result in $[0,\pi/2]$ and you will get the result.

Comment: So, my result is wrong because tan is infinite at pi/2?

Comment: Recall that in your result you will actually have a term like this:$$\frac{1}{ab}\arctan(\frac{b}{a}\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}))=\frac{1}{ab}\arctan( \infty )=\frac{1}{ab}\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: @AndrewFount, because $y=\tan x$ is not increasing in $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: @Mufasa, you are right.

Comment: @Andrew Fount -- that is essentially correct.  The tan function goes to infnity and then jumps to - infinity and that introduces a discontinuity.

Answer (score 1):

**Some Background on Integration by Substitution**

It is important to understand the assumptions one makes in [Integration by Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Definition).

Let $I$ denote the integral given by $I=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$.

**Condition $(i)$:**
 We assume that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

**Condition $(ii)$:**
The inverse function $u^{-1}$, of $u(x)$ is continuously differentiable on $[u(a),u(b)]$.

Under Conditions $1$ and $2$, we have

> $$\begin{align}I=&\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\\\\&=\int_{u(a)}^{u(b)}f(u^{-1}(t))\frac{du^{-1}(t)}{dt}\,dt \tag 1\end{align}$$

Note that the relationship expressed in $(1)$ can be obtained formally through the substitution $u(x)=t$, under Assumptions $(i)$ and $(ii)$.

---

**Application to Evaluating $\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{a^2\sin^2(x)+b^2\cos^2(x)}\,dx$**

To apply the substitution in $(1)$ correctly to evaluate the integral of interest, one must ensure that both $(i)$ and $(ii)$ are satisfied.

Since $f(x)=\frac{1}{a^2\sin^2(x)+b^2\cos^2(x)}$ is continuous for $x\in [a,b]$ and **Condition $1$** is satisfied.

The substitution used in the reference cited in the OP is $\tan(x)=t$.  Note that for $x\in [0,\pi]$ the inverse function for the tangent function is given by

$$\tan^{-1}(t)=\begin{cases}\arctan(t)&, t>0\\\\\pi+\arctan(t)&,t<0 \tag 2\end{cases}$$

where the $-\pi/2 < \arctan(x)<\pi/2$ is the principal branch of the inverse tangent function.  The inverse tangent is not even continuous at $0$ and we cannot apply, therefore, the substitution over the interval $x\in [0,\pi]$.

Instead, we can write the integral as the sum

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi f(x)\,dx&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\int_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon}f(x)\,dx+\int_{\pi/2+\epsilon}^\pi f(x)\,dx\right)
\end{align}$$

where $f(x)=\frac{1}{a^2\sin^2(x)+b^2\cos^2(x)}$.

The inverse tangent function $\tan^{-1}(x)$ as expressed in $(2)$ is continuously differentiable on each separate interval $x>0$ and $x<0$ and so, **Condition $2$** is satisfied on each separate interval.

Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon}f(x)\,dx&=\int_0^{\infty}f(\arctan(t))\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt\\\\
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\pi/2+\epsilon}^\pi f(x)\,dx&=\int_{-\infty}^0f(\pi+\arctan(t))\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt \tag 3
\end{align}$$

Since $f(x)$ is even and $\pi$-periodic, then the second equality in $(3)$ is identical to the first.  Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi f(x)\,dx&=2\int_0^\infty \frac{f(\arctan(t))}{1+t^2}\,dt\\\\
&=2\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{a^2t^2+b^2}\,dt\\\\
&=\left. \frac{2\arctan(at/b)}{ab}\right|_{0}^{\pi/2}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{ab}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

This very integral, with a little manipulation, is referenced in [the Jeffrey paper](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/importan.pdf) so the nice form in that paper can be attained by observing that $\tan^{-1}(\tan x)$ has the same discontinuities as the original integral, so we may hope to cancel them out by setting
$$\frac1{ab}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}a\tan x\right)=\frac1{ab}\left\{x+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}a\tan x\right)-\tan^{-1}(\tan x)\right\}$$ Now,
$$\begin{align}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}a\tan x\right)-\tan^{-1}(\tan x) & =\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{b}a\tan x-\tan x}{1+\frac{b}a\tan^2x}\right) \\ & =\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(b-a)\sin2x}{(a+b)-(b-a)\cos2x}\right) \end{align}$$ after a little algebra, so
$$\int\frac1{a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x}dx=\frac1{ab}\left\{x+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(b-a)\sin2x}{(a+b)-(b-a)\cos2x}\right)\right\}+C$$ removes all discontinuities and even checks by differentiation.